# Facebook sharing does not display images

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-opengraph

I'm trying to share my webpage. Now I got the sharing dialog working but the images attached to it is not displaying. Is there something missing? below are my codes.
Credit to [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TdLh3.png)

```
<meta property="og:url"           content="MY_SITE_DOMAIN_URL" />
<meta property="og:type"          content="website" />
<meta property="og:title"         content="MySite" />
<meta property="og:description"   content="MySite Description" />
<meta property="og:image"         content="https://homestack.com/photo/agent1.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image:width" content="500">
<meta property="og:image:height" content="500">
```

And this is the javascript that trigger the dialog share

```
var fbShare = function(url, title, descr, image, winWidth, winHeight) {
var winTop = (screen.height / 2) - (winHeight / 2);
var winLeft = (screen.width / 2) - (winWidth / 2);
window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&p[title]=' + title + '&p[summary]=' + descr + '&p[url]=' + url + '&p[images][0]=' + image, 'sharer', 'top=' + winTop + ',left=' + winLeft + ',toolbar=0,status=0,width='+winWidth+',height='+winHeight);
}
```

And this the link that triggers the js function

```
<a href="javascript:fbShare('MY_SITE_DOMAIN_URL', 'MySite', 'MySite description', 'https://homestack.com/photo/agent1.jpg', 520, 350)">Share on Facebook</a>
```

When checking the facebook debugger I have this
[image]

[image: [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/ques]tions/14829040/facebook-sharer-popup-window

This is the markup in my html head tag
[image]

Seems that it cannot fetch the image. Based on my meta the image I used is a public photo. Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: You can not pass any of those values dynamically at runtime any more. You specify only the URL to share, and Facebook will fetch everything else from there. And to see if your OG meta data is correct, simply but the URL through the Facebook debug tool.

Comment: Updated my question please help. Thanks

Comment: That sounds like it can’t read your OG meta data at all. Can you give an actual example URL please?

Comment: Sorry but I can't provide the actual url cause its still under development and still prone to some security issue. But I can attach the image of the markup in the HTML head tag

Comment: @CBroe found the problem it seems that facebook caches the results. You were right about facebook not being able to read the metadata. When I double check it was not outputted properly. Then facebook cache the result and needs to wait a few minutes for it to reflect. Thanks for the help